# Python: binary mode vs encoding and its sha256

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, hashcode

I am again in the mysteries of python:
Can you tell me why created sha256 are not the same (release.md stays the same):

```
import re, os, os.path, hashlib, time, sys

with open("release.md", "rb") as f:
    h = f.read()
    #print(h)
    print(hashlib.sha256(h).hexdigest())
    

with open("release.md", "r", encoding=sys.getdefaultencoding()) as f:
    h = f.read()
    #print(h)
    print(hashlib.sha256(h.encode(sys.getdefaultencoding())).hexdigest())
```

Output:

```
8c1938c9b495afe666d41a23cb6d108b3c351d6c8b5aca7019e214df1c47e240
32b8f1a46cea09e6c358390c8a81b80e233bd6c991c010cad6ad5489362e20d3
```

Its python 3.9.1 on windows10

Comment: You get different files. Binary files are 1-1 the bytes, but text file (second case), you get CR\LF (\r\l) into just one character: NL (\n). Also encoding may not be able to do round-trip

Comment: Note: it is mostly on Windows, where the recommended ASCII termination of line is used (contrary on most other systems (and C was done for Unix, so they used this trick: distinguish "binary/text" file on opening, which python copied.

Comment: A first debugging step would be to compare the two byte sequences *before hashing*…

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that its up to windows specific linefeed, the open function will use transitions to "\r\n"

see Parameter newline: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open

```
import re, os, os.path, hashlib, time, sys

with open("release.md", "rb") as f:
    h = f.read()
    #print(h)
    print(hashlib.sha256(h).hexdigest())

e=sys.getdefaultencoding()

with open("release.md", "r", encoding=e, newline="\n") as f:
    h = f.read()
    #print(h)
    print(hashlib.sha256(h.encode(e)).hexdigest())
```

makes it equal.